# Why does Facebook show the time of seen, the same as the time of sending message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I use Facebook on my computer. I have this problem when I send someone any message, and the message gets seen, the time of seen is the same as the time I sent it.

Comment: Is there a chance that the recipient really did receive the message at the same time you sent it?

Comment: See the comment below. @MaryC.fromNZ

Answer (score 2):

This can happen for several reasons. The most likely is that the recipient has Facebook open on one of their devices, causing any message to be shown as read as soon as it arrives (aka the same time it was sent). Alternatively, the recipient could have a message client reading their Facebook messages for them , thus causing every message to be read as soon as it arrives.

Comment: No man no. It doesn't get seen right on the moment it was sent. There's that sent arrow (on a PC) appearing under the message until the person on other side sees the message and when it gets seen, the seen time is same as the sent time.

Comment: So the "seen" indicator does not appear for some time, and, when it does, it displays the sent time? That would indicate that the person has a client that doesn't play well with Facebook's chat times.

Comment: Can you be more clear and untechnical? @Michelfrancis Bustillos

Comment: I shall try: The "seen" indicator does not appear until a while after you send the message, but, when it does, it displays the time you sent it? If so, it seems that the person you are messaging is using a program or app to view or alert them of their messages that is messing up how Facebook knowing when a message is received and when it is read. Does this happen only when messaging one person?

Comment: No, it happens with every person I message. And one person I know uses Opera browser on android, so I don't think there's something that reads their message without their consent.

Comment: Possibly an Android notification handler?

Comment: I forgot to tell it's Opera mini browser there, it runs a very basic version of facebook. So, there is hardly any notification service there, you have to open your account in that browser and read the message on your own.

Comment: Then its probably something to do with how the carrier is handling it, or it could be just a Facebook glitch. How you brought it up on Facebook's support community?

Comment: I haven't consulted Facebook support yet.

Comment: That's probably the best course of action. Post a question I'm their community.

Answer (score 1):

1. They might have deleted your message. Thus, the time of seen is the same as the time of sending message.
2. If they use Messenger, your message is shown in the notification area and they see it immediately.